# What has the [[Scope]] internal property been replaced with in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What has the [[Scope]] internal property been replaced with in ES6?

I can find it in ES5, but no mention of it in ES6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `[[Scope]]` has been replaced by `[[Environment]]` in ES2015. [Section 9.2.4 (FunctionInitialize)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-functioninitialize) states:

> 6. Set the [[Environment]] internal slot of F to the value of Scope.

whereas ES5 says this in [section 13.2 (Creating Function Objects)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2):

> 9. Set the [[Scope]] internal property of F to the value of Scope.

Comment: The first link refers to ECMAScript 2017 now, and does not have "Set the [[Environment]] internal slot of F to the value of Scope.", as far as I can see

Comment: @Brian: indeed, changed the link. In the [TC39 working copy](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-functioninitialize) it now says in step 5: "Set F.[[Environment]] to Scope."